# Python: как не добавлять элемент, неудовлетворяющий условию при генерации списка?

Tags: python

Есть такой список, нужно получить на выходе список, содержащий только те строки, которые представляют собой числа

```py
elements = ['1', 'sdf2', '3', '32', '2sf']
```

Как при генерации списка в ветке `else` не добавлять элемент вообще?

Так нельзя - нет ветки `else`

```py
result = [element if element.isdigit() for element in elements]
```

А так приходится добавлять либо `''`, либо `None` или еще что-то. Как не добавлять элемент?

```py
result = [element if element.isdigit() else '' for element in elements]
```

Comment: `list(filter(str.isdigit, elements))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elements  = ['1', 'sdf2', '3', '32', '2sf']
m = [i for i in elements if i.isdigit()]
print(m)
```

Если только все числа целые, не дробные. Если с дробными нужно напишите.