# Как вывести индексы вхождений символа с помощью list comprehension?

Tags: python

Пусть у меня есть какая-то строка например `some_str = "вася бежал по полю и умер"` и я хочу получить список всех индексов вхождений буквы "а". То есть я хочу сделать следующее:

```
some_str = "вася бежал по полю и умер"
lst = []
for i in range(len(some_str)):
    if some_str[i] == "а":
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```

То есть вывод на данную строку будет следующим:

```
[1, 8]
```

Есть ли возможность здесь использовать list comprehension? То есть у меня была идея написать, что то типо следующего:

```
lst = [x == "а" for x in some_str]
```

Но естественно, это не дает желаемого результата. Есть ли возможность использовать list comprehension в моем случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, также, как и в обычном цикле :)

```py
some_str = "вася бежал по полю и умер"
lst = [i for i in range(len(some_str)) if some_str[i] == "а"]
print(lst)
```

**Выхлоп:**

```py
[1, 8]
```

---

*Очень забавно, что я пару часов назад [**задавал вопрос**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1391111/python-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) на эту тему =)*

Answer (score 1):

я бы воспользовался `enumerate()` методом, который возвращает `индекс:значение` для итерируемых типов данных.

```py
>>> some_str = "вася бежал по полю и умер"
>>> [index_ for index_, element in enumerate(some_str) if element == 'а'] 
[1, 8]
```